# Bash remove half of the files in the directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove half of the files in the corpora directory to make my spam filter trained a little bit faster and, in the future, save some space. Normally I would do it by trial and error, but since these files took a while to download etc, plus it's shell (which I am *obviously* not an expert in), I do not want to mess this up.

I would try something like this:

```
ls *.* > list
for i in 'cat list'; do rm -f i++; done
```

But im pretty sure `i++` like this isn't a proper way to skip every second item in the list. **Perhaps I should use some other loop?**

Secondly, there are two types of files in that directory:

1. 0000.* to 1500.*
2. 0000.* to 0250.*

I want to delete half of the first type and half of the second type. Since they're probably sorted a standard way in the list, meaning that from 0000.* to 0250.* they interweave and then after 0.250.* the first type remains only, it might be deleted the wrong way (all from the second type could be deleted).

So IMHO, I should do it like this:

```
Both types delete 0000.*
Both types skip 0001.*
Both types delete 0002.*
etc.
```

**Do you guys have an idea how to delete these files like above?**

Comment: [`ls` and `for` do not mix.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Whitespaces in filenames will *wreck* your script.

Comment: your script fails because of (1) use `$i`, not `i++` and (2) use backtics or better `$(cat list)` and not single quotes. Your script can be improved by changing `*.*` into `*`, or better removing the ls by using `for i in *; do` or better by using `rm -f *`. However, this will not answer your question, see the accepted answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to delete every second file, then you can use a simple alternating state machine. Since `*.*` will give you the files in sorted order, you can just delete every second file, with something like:

```
del=1
for fspec in *.* ; do
    if [[ ${del} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        del=0
        echo rm ${fspec}
    else
        echo ok ${fspec}
        del=1
    fi
done
```

If you run that script you'll get a series of alternating lines saying:

```
rm file1
ok file2
rm file3
ok file4
```

and so on.

Once you're happy with the behaviour, you can comment out the `ok` line entirely and remove the `echo` from the `rm` line.

---

However, if your intent is to actually delete all files of the form `NNNN.*`, where `NNNN` is in the set `{0000, 0002, 0004, ..., 9998}`, that can be done more concisely (again, remove the `echo` when you're happy):

```
for id in {0000..9998..2} ; do
    echo rm -f ${id}.*
done
```

That `0000` will ensure the strings are four digits long, assuming you have a recent enough `bash`. If it doesn't, you can just use:

```
for id in {0..9998..2} ; do
    echo rm -f $(printf "%04d" ${id}).*
done
```

---

Regardless of the method you choose, I'd be making a backup of the directory you're working in before testing as well.

Comment: Edit mayhem I see here, Sir! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, this does not remove 0002.*, 0004.* etc, but 2.*, 4.*. Or I am doing something wrong. Still, from now on it's easy.

Comment: @JamesPond, yes, silly me, should have looked at *both* ends of the output. Have adjusted the answer to fix.